# Override loader query parameters in Webpack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, webpack

I have a somewhat unique problem. I'm using webpack as my asset pipeline for a ruby on rails project. I use plugins which help bridge the gap between both systems but since I don't parse any of my ERB/HTML files with webpack, any images directly referenced from there do not get compiled.

I solved this by using `require.context` within one of my main JavaScript modules and it works, for the most part. The problem is that the files I'm copying use [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) and as a result, files smaller than my limit don't get copied.

I can't manually override the `require.context` to use [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) because of the complex query parameters that differ from development to production builds.

Is there a way to override just the limit query parameter from the `require.context` statement. If not, what are some other solutions for this problem.